# Precise footer control (include line breaks and shift position)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, posters

I am preparing a poster and using `fancyhdr` to include content at the bottom of the page. I have two issues:

- `\cfoot{}` is not centered, this can be solved using `\makebox{}`, however, the later command does not seem to allow new lines and this is necessary since the text is too long otherwise.
- I would like to be able to shift the footers up along the vertical axis (in other words move them away from the bottom of the paper)

I am not sure if `fancyhdr` is the best solution, but currently it is the closest to what I want.

Here is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=36in, paperheight=27in, margin=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt
\columnseprule=3pt
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


% Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\fancyfootoffset[LO]{-8cm}

% Organization logo and presentation footer
\lfoot{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}} %insitution logo
\rfoot{Poster presented at XXX. Tokyo, Japan}

% Not centered:
%\cfoot{\Huge\textbf{Acknowledgements} This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  \\ This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text }

% cannot introduce linebreak
\cfoot{\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\Huge \textbf{Acknowledgements} This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text }}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\lipsum[1-90]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a single page, I would use tikzpagenodes and the `current page footer area` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest \parbox, \raisebox, \makebox to get what ever placement you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=36in, paperheight=27in, margin=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt
\columnseprule=3pt
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


% Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
%\fancyfootoffset[LO]{-8cm}

% Organization logo and presentation footer
\lfoot{\raisebox{-0.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}}} %insitution logo
\rfoot{Poster presented at XXX. Tokyo, Japan}


\cfoot{\raisebox{0cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
 \makebox[0pt]{\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\centering \Huge \textbf{Acknowledgements} This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text  This is acknowledgement text }}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\lipsum[1-90]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! For this to work in the actual poster I still need `\fancyfootoffset[LO]{-1cm}` and I had to play around with some of the `\raisebox` and `\parbox` inputs, but now it looks exactly like I wanted. I will read more about those commands.

Comment: If you want to center the footer I wouldn't add an (unsymmetric) offset. You can always use \hspace{-1cm} before the picture to move it in the margin.